# Dual navigation solution

Tags: mobile, navigation, dropdown

Anyone has any suggestions to avoid double dropdown for navigation for a mobile app ( i.e. dropdown 1: main menu nav, dropdown 2: secondary nav within a particular page content. ) Just trying to think of any unique ways to navigate or break up the redundancy of dropdowns by having a secondary nav behave in a different way. Just looking for suggestions. TYIA

Answer (score 1):

Our solution on TED isn't perfect (for one thing, it's behind the dreaded hamburger menu), but it at least avoids the double dropdown issue. If you visit [TED.com](https://ted.com), then tap on the hamburger in the upper left, you'll see a slide-out site menu. Because some sections of our site are very deep, tapping on a section like About—one of the deepest sections in our site—opens a sub-menu. Then tap on, say Our Organization and you'll see available sections there.

[image]

Again, far from perfect, but it allowed us to get a very deep site into one menu without using a ton of real estate.

Comment: When you use current links in an answer, you create an answer that ages poorly, or which may display differently on different devices.  For example, I don't see any hamburger menu when I visit ted.com.  I have to shrink my browser for it to be visible.  So instead use static images to convey the idea (which I think you can't attach yet), so I'm attaching them for you.

Comment: @michael McWatters thanks for the response. I am actually very familiar with the ted sites and nav as I was one of the designers for tedmed.com back in the days. For this project we currently have such hamburger menu in place and this is not an option for me, we are trying to stray away from that. Thanks for the feedback nonetheless. :)